# How to read documents while adding other documents in Mongoose?

Tags: database, mongoose, document

My app receives a new document and save it to database at any time. How can I make sure that there will not be conflict in the worst case that I read existing documents while a new document is being saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should have a problem as the insert and update operations should be atomic in mongoDB

from the docs:

> In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single
>   document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents
>   within a single document.

Comment: Do you mean they cannot be executed at the same time? Instead, once writing (or reading) process is in progress, the other cannot be executed?

Comment: Exactly, it is promissed that the while you write no other action will be taken on this objects